# MUI Datagrid display array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-datatable

I am using Redux to fetch data from my API and this is what my data looks like:

[image]

The problem I am facing is a way to display the data from the array of objects named question.

I am using render Cell to render data for rows currently, here is the snippet of that:

```
return {
      field: item.dbCol, // I've a config file, which reads field name from a loop
      type: item.fieldType,
      width: item.columnWidth,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return item.elements.map((element, iterator)=>{
          switch (element.columnType) {
             case 'Question':
              return params.row.question.map((item)=><p>{item.answer}</p>);
}
```

This is what I've tried so far, but I'm not able to get the data from the question object with the right column!

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try valueGetter and iterate your "Questions". It should work.

I need the same solution. I will prepare this iteration part and update here. Meanwhile you can think if something.

[Role List with Permissions as Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFxKL.png)

[Similar data as yours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ukR.png)

```
{ field: 'permissions', headerName:'Permissions', type: 'string', width: 200,
            valueGetter:(params)=>{ return params.row.permissions[0].name; }
},
```